# Running 2 sites on docker-nginx-php server

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, nginx, docker, containers

I'm using Docker and serving a PHP API server with nginx and mysql. Now I'm trying to add a separated static website but failed to do so by modiying **nginx.conf**. The following is my folder structure.

```
+ images
|+ php
|-- Dockerfile
||+ app
||-+ public
|||-- index.php
||+ home <-- TRYING TO GET THIS WORKING (Same level as app folder)
||-- index.html  <-- TRYING TO THIS WORKING 
|+ nginx
|-- nginx.conf
|-- Dockerfile
- README.md
- docker-compose.yml
```

Here is my nginx conf.

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name api.example.com;
  root /app/public;
  index index.php index.htm index.html;

  location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
  }

  location /index.php {
      include fastcgi_params;
      fastcgi_connect_timeout 10s;
      fastcgi_read_timeout 10s;
      fastcgi_buffers 256 4k;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      fastcgi_pass php:9000;
  }

    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*";
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, OPTIONS";
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, authorization, accept";
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    root /home;
    index index.htm index.html

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

}
```

I can access api.example.com and everything works fine. But when I go to example.com, it shows *404 not found. nginx/1.114* (Does it have anything to do with docker-compose.yml?)

Thanks!

Comment: Could you paste your Dockerfiles and docker-compose.yml as well, please?
Also could you regenerate your folder structure listing using 'tree' command (current is hard to read)?

Btw my first guess is that you have wrong path in nginx conf ('root /home'), but to confirm it Dockerfile is needed.

2nd thing is you probably should have different container for static files and use compose to start both of them.